# Zoom content relatively to the pointer location

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using `transform: scale(); transform-origin: 0 0;` to zoom page content. I'm changing scale when the user scrolls the page and set `transform-origin` based on pointer placement. It' works, but has one problem. If the user moves mouse pointer and scrolls, content jumps to the pointer and zooms there. What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it? I need my transform origin to be the pointer location on the table. Here is my code and working fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/vaxobasilidze/v0pLwqd8/1/

Hover the table and scroll. It'll be zoomed. Then move mouse pointer to another place on the table and scroll again. Content starts jumping. I need to get zooming effect similar to the google maps have. What is the problem in my code?

```js
var zX = 1;
document.getElementById("mainDiv").addEventListener("wheel", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var x = e.pageX;
    var y = e.pageY;
    var pageWidth = $('#mainDiv').width();
    var pageHeight = $('#mainDiv').height();
    var dir;
    if (e.deltaY > 0){
        dir = -0.05;
    }
    else{
        dir = 0.05;
    }
    if((zX + dir) >= 0.05){
        zX += dir;
    }
    //Math.floor(x/pageWidth*100)+'% '+Math.floor(y/pageHeight*100)+'%'
    $('#mainDiv').css({'transform': 'scale('+zX+')', 'transform-origin': Math.floor(x/pageWidth*100)+'% '+Math.floor(y/pageHeight*100)+'%'});
    return;
});


function showAudioDb(){
  var dbInterval = setInterval(function(){
    var dbLeft = Math.floor(Math.random() * 60) + 1;
    var dbRight = Math.floor(Math.random() * 60) + 1;
    var leftCover = Math.round(dbLeft/60*100);
    var rightCover = Math.round(dbRight/60*100);
    $('.audioLeft audioCover').animate({height: leftCover+'%'}, "slow")
    $('.audioRight audioCover').animate({height: rightCover+'%'}, "slow")
  }, 500);
}

showAudioDb();
```

```css
.channels {
  /*border-collapse: collapse;*/
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 1px solid rgba(30, 30, 30, 1);
  border-radius: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: url(images/comment-bg3.png) repeat;
  resize: both;
}

.channels td {
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(30, 30, 30, 1);
}

.channels td:first-child {
  border-left: none;
}

.channelHeader {
  height: 7%;
  text-align: center;
  background: url(images/comment-bg2.png) repeat;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
}

.audioVideo {
  height: 79%;
}

.channelInfo {
  height: 7%;
  max-height: 7%;
  text-align: center;
  background: url(images/comment-bg2.png) repeat;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(30, 30, 30, 1);
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(30, 30, 30, 1);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
}

.channelInfo td {
  border-radius: 2px 2px 0 0;
}

.channelInfoValues {
  height: 7%;
  max-height: 7%;
  text-align: center;
}

.str0 {stroke:white;stroke-width:3.97;stroke-miterlimit:22.9256}
.str1 {stroke:#999999;stroke-width:3.97;stroke-miterlimit:22.9256}
.fil1 {fill:none}
.fil0 {fill:#333333}

.sound {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.audiodb {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.levels {
  position: absolute;
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: 5%;
  top: 5%;
  height: 1px;
  left: 10%;
  background: silver;
  z-index: 300;
}

.level1 {
  top: 15%;
}

.level2 {
  top: 35%;
}

.level3 {
  top: 95%;
}

.audioBackground {
  width: 30%;
  height: 90%;
  left: 20%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  background: #ff0000;
  background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ff0000 0%, #ff0000 7%, #faff00 20%, #00ff2a 38%, #006d10 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ff0000), color-stop(7%,#ff0000), color-stop(20%,#faff00), color-stop(38%,#00ff2a), color-stop(100%,#006d10)); /* Chrome4-9,Safari4-5 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ff0000 0%,#ff0000 7%,#faff00 20%,#00ff2a 38%,#006d10 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ff0000 0%,#ff0000 7%,#faff00 20%,#00ff2a 38%,#006d10 100%); /* Opera 11.10-11.50 */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ff0000 0%,#ff0000 7%,#faff00 20%,#00ff2a 38%,#006d10 100%); /* IE10 preview */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ff0000 0%,#ff0000 7%,#faff00 20%,#00ff2a 38%,#006d10 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ff0000', endColorstr='#006d10',GradientType=0 );
}

.audioRight {
  left: 60%;
}

.audioCover {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30%;
  background: grey;
}
.audioNumbers {
  width: 10%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
}
.db {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 15%;
}
.db p {
  margin-top: -5px;
}
.max {
  top: 5%;
}
.high {
  top: 15%;
}
.normal {
  top: 35%;
}
.low {
  top: 95%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/css-element-queries/0.4.0/ResizeSensor.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/css-element-queries/0.4.0/ElementQueries.min.js"></script>
<table class="channels ui-draggable ui-resizable" style="width: 476px; height: 266px; position: relative;" oncontextmenu="return false;" id="mainDiv">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="channelHeader ui-draggable-handle">
      <td colspan="5" class="channelName" id="channel1" audiopid="[0x33]" audiostream1="format:mp2,type:audio,pid:[0x33],width:0,height:0" interface="192.168.222.15" method="info" multicast="239.10.20.101" port="6000" protocol="udp" resolution="1920x1080" serviceid="1" servicename="undefined" serviceprovider="provider" videopid="[0x31]" videostream="format:h264,type:video,pid:[0x31],width:1920,height:1080">undefined</td>
      <td colspan="2" class="channelNumber">1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="audioVideo">
      <td colspan="5" class="vid"></td>
      <td colspan="2" class="sound">
        <div class="audiodb">
            <div class="audioNumbers">
              <span class="db max"><p>0</p></span>
              <span class="db high"><p>6</p></span>
              <span class="db normal"><p>18</p></span>
              <span class="db low"><p>60</p></span>
            </div>
            <div class="audioBackground audioLeft">
              <div class="audioCover"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="audioBackground audioRight">
              <div class="audioCover"></div>
            </div>
            <span class="levels level0"></span>
            <span class="levels level1"></span>
            <span class="levels level2"></span>
            <span class="levels level3"></span>
          </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="channelInfo">
      <td class="resolution">Resolution</td>
      <td class="aspect">Aspect</td>
      <td class="fps">FPS</td>
      <td class="vformat">V-Format</td>
      <td class="aformat">A-Format</td>
      <td>Left</td><td>Right</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="channelInfoValues">
      <td class="resolValue">1920x1080</td>
      <td class="aspectValue">---</td>
      <td class="fpsValue">---</td>
      <td class="vformatValue">H-264</td>
      <td class="aformatValue">MP2</td>
      <td class="leftBarValue">---</td>
      <td class="rightBarValue">---</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: what is supposed to happen ? i see nothing ..

Comment: Well the problem is that your are setting the transform-origin according to the pointer position. Removing the transform-origin from your js and adding it to the '.channels' class in css like this: transform-origin: 0 0 0; should fix it.

Comment: @CataJohn But #mainDiv and .channels is the same element. How will it help? can you edit my code please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, looks like we have to take zoom into account when calculating transform positions.

Take a look at this approach. I used `translate` and `scale` transitions and calculated coordinates according to zoom.

```js
var current = {x: 0, y: 0, zoom: 1};
var max = 5, min = 0.1;
document.getElementById("mainDiv").addEventListener("wheel", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var x = e.pageX, //you should subtract mainDiv x offset here if any
        y = e.pageY, //you should subtract mainDiv y offset here if any
        coef = e.deltaY > 0 ? 0.7 : 1.2,
        nz = current.zoom * coef,
        // calculate new positions according to zoom 
        cx = x - (x - current.x) * coef,
        cy = y - (y - current.y) * coef;
    if (nz < max && nz > min) {
    current.zoom = nz;
    current.x = cx;
    current.y = cy;
    this.style.transform
        = 'translate('+cx+'px, '+cy+'px) '
        + 'scale('+nz+')';
        }
    return;
});


function showAudioDb(){
  var dbInterval = setInterval(function(){
    var dbLeft = Math.floor(Math.random() * 60) + 1;
    var dbRight = Math.floor(Math.random() * 60) + 1;
    var leftCover = Math.round(dbLeft/60*100);
    var rightCover = Math.round(dbRight/60*100);
    $('.audioLeft audioCover').animate({height: leftCover+'%'}, "slow")
    $('.audioRight audioCover').animate({height: rightCover+'%'}, "slow")
  }, 500);
}

showAudioDb();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.channels {
  /*border-collapse: collapse;*/
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 1px solid rgba(30, 30, 30, 1);
  border-radius: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: url(images/comment-bg3.png) repeat;
  resize: both;
}

.channels td {
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(30, 30, 30, 1);
}

.channels td:first-child {
  border-left: none;
}

.channelHeader {
  height: 7%;
  text-align: center;
  background: url(images/comment-bg2.png) repeat;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
}

.audioVideo {
  height: 79%;
}

.channelInfo {
  height: 7%;
  max-height: 7%;
  text-align: center;
  background: url(images/comment-bg2.png) repeat;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(30, 30, 30, 1);
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(30, 30, 30, 1);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
}

.channelInfo td {
  border-radius: 2px 2px 0 0;
}

.channelInfoValues {
  height: 7%;
  max-height: 7%;
  text-align: center;
}

.str0 {stroke:white;stroke-width:3.97;stroke-miterlimit:22.9256}
.str1 {stroke:#999999;stroke-width:3.97;stroke-miterlimit:22.9256}
.fil1 {fill:none}
.fil0 {fill:#333333}

.sound {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.audiodb {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.levels {
  position: absolute;
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: 5%;
  top: 5%;
  height: 1px;
  left: 10%;
  background: silver;
  z-index: 300;
}

.level1 {
  top: 15%;
}

.level2 {
  top: 35%;
}

.level3 {
  top: 95%;
}

.audioBackground {
  width: 30%;
  height: 90%;
  left: 20%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  background: #ff0000;
  background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ff0000 0%, #ff0000 7%, #faff00 20%, #00ff2a 38%, #006d10 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ff0000), color-stop(7%,#ff0000), color-stop(20%,#faff00), color-stop(38%,#00ff2a), color-stop(100%,#006d10)); /* Chrome4-9,Safari4-5 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ff0000 0%,#ff0000 7%,#faff00 20%,#00ff2a 38%,#006d10 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ff0000 0%,#ff0000 7%,#faff00 20%,#00ff2a 38%,#006d10 100%); /* Opera 11.10-11.50 */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ff0000 0%,#ff0000 7%,#faff00 20%,#00ff2a 38%,#006d10 100%); /* IE10 preview */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ff0000 0%,#ff0000 7%,#faff00 20%,#00ff2a 38%,#006d10 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ff0000', endColorstr='#006d10',GradientType=0 );
}

.audioRight {
  left: 60%;
}

.audioCover {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30%;
  background: grey;
}
.audioNumbers {
  width: 10%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
}
.db {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 15%;
}
.db p {
  margin-top: -5px;
}
.max {
  top: 5%;
}
.high {
  top: 15%;
}
.normal {
  top: 35%;
}
.low {
  top: 95%;
}

#mainDiv {
  transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
  transform-origin: 0 0 0;
  transform: translate(0,0) scale(1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/css-element-queries/0.4.0/ResizeSensor.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/css-element-queries/0.4.0/ElementQueries.min.js"></script>
<table class="channels ui-draggable ui-resizable" style="width: 476px; height: 266px; position: relative;" oncontextmenu="return false;" id="mainDiv">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="channelHeader ui-draggable-handle">
      <td colspan="5" class="channelName" id="channel1" audiopid="[0x33]" audiostream1="format:mp2,type:audio,pid:[0x33],width:0,height:0" interface="192.168.222.15" method="info" multicast="239.10.20.101" port="6000" protocol="udp" resolution="1920x1080" serviceid="1" servicename="undefined" serviceprovider="provider" videopid="[0x31]" videostream="format:h264,type:video,pid:[0x31],width:1920,height:1080">undefined</td>
      <td colspan="2" class="channelNumber">1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="audioVideo">
      <td colspan="5" class="vid"></td>
      <td colspan="2" class="sound">
        <div class="audiodb">
            <div class="audioNumbers">
              <span class="db max"><p>0</p></span>
              <span class="db high"><p>6</p></span>
              <span class="db normal"><p>18</p></span>
              <span class="db low"><p>60</p></span>
            </div>
            <div class="audioBackground audioLeft">
              <div class="audioCover"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="audioBackground audioRight">
              <div class="audioCover"></div>
            </div>
            <span class="levels level0"></span>
            <span class="levels level1"></span>
            <span class="levels level2"></span>
            <span class="levels level3"></span>
          </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="channelInfo">
      <td class="resolution">Resolution</td>
      <td class="aspect">Aspect</td>
      <td class="fps">FPS</td>
      <td class="vformat">V-Format</td>
      <td class="aformat">A-Format</td>
      <td>Left</td><td>Right</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="channelInfoValues">
      <td class="resolValue">1920x1080</td>
      <td class="aspectValue">---</td>
      <td class="fpsValue">---</td>
      <td class="vformatValue">H-264</td>
      <td class="aformatValue">MP2</td>
      <td class="leftBarValue">---</td>
      <td class="rightBarValue">---</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I have also tried this to make it smoother and no question, it works much better, but try to zoom to different points when the table is zoomed several times already. It's pretty hard to focus on another coordinates. If you help me to fix this, I'll accept the answer with bounty.

Comment: The main problem here is that when the table is already zoomed, transform-origin point jumps to the center of the viewpoint, which makes it harder to focus on one point.

Comment: @VaxoBasilidze take a look at my update. Seems that idea with `transform-origin` doesn't work because we need to take zoom into account when calculating new coordinates

Comment: That works really good! Just a little thing to fix: When the table is too big, I can scroll it to the right or bottom, but the table's left part gets hidden. Can I make it available for the user to see the left part as well without zooming out? For example, let them scroll to the left as well, if the content passes the window. I'll accept your answer anyway, but maybe you can help me with this as well? Thank you.

Comment: @VaxoBasilidze Yes, I see what you're talking about. One solution is to make the table draggable. Usually zoom-to-point functionality comes with dragging, because it's really convenient.

Comment: I have tried: $('#mainDiv').draggable(); Did not work. Why? Jquery is included.

Comment: Oh right, i needed to include jquery-ui as well. but another problem in this case is that I have many tables like in the fiddle contained in another larger table, which i'm trying to make zoomable. Small tables are already draggable and that causes problems for making large table draggable as well.

Comment: @Vaxo if you create a separate question and share some details there, I'll be glad to help you

Comment: I think I found out what to do. Setting correct drag handle is the solution. Thank you for your help! I'll try to fix it myself to not bother you anymore :)

Answer (score 1):

```js
var zX = 1;
document.getElementById("mainDiv").addEventListener("wheel", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var x = e.pageX;
    var y = e.pageY;
    var pageWidth = $('#mainDiv').width();
    var pageHeight = $('#mainDiv').height();
    var dir;
    if (e.deltaY > 0) {
        dir = -0.05;
    } else {
        dir = 0.05;
    }
    if ((zX + dir) >= 0.05) {
        zX += dir;
    }
    //Math.floor(x/pageWidth*100)+'% '+Math.floor(y/pageHeight*100)+'%'
    if (zX >= 1) {
      $('#mainDiv tbody').css({
          'transform': 'scale(' + zX + ')',
          'transform-origin': Math.floor(x/pageWidth*100)+'% '+Math.floor(y/pageHeight*100)+'%'
      });
    } else {
      zX = 1; 
    }

    return;
});

function showAudioDb() {
    var dbInterval = setInterval(function () {
        var dbLeft = Math.floor(Math.random() * 60) + 1;
        var dbRight = Math.floor(Math.random() * 60) + 1;
        var leftCover = Math.round(dbLeft / 60 * 100);
        var rightCover = Math.round(dbRight / 60 * 100);
        $('.audioLeft audioCover').animate({
            height: leftCover + '%'
        }, "slow")
        $('.audioRight audioCover').animate({
            height: rightCover + '%'
        }, "slow")
    }, 500);
}

showAudioDb();
```

```css
.channels {
    /*border-collapse: collapse;*/
    border-spacing: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 1px solid rgba(30, 30, 30, 1);
    border-radius: 4px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: url(images/comment-bg3.png) repeat;
    resize: both;
}

.channels td {
    border-left: 1px solid rgba(30, 30, 30, 1);
}

.channels td:first-child {
    border-left: none;
}

.channelHeader {
    height: 7%;
    text-align: center;
    background: url(images/comment-bg2.png) repeat;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
}

.audioVideo {
    height: 79%;
}

.channelInfo {
    height: 7%;
    max-height: 7%;
    text-align: center;
    background: url(images/comment-bg2.png) repeat;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(30, 30, 30, 1);
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(30, 30, 30, 1);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
}

.channelInfo td {
    border-radius: 2px 2px 0 0;
}

.channelInfoValues {
    height: 7%;
    max-height: 7%;
    text-align: center;
}

.str0 {
    stroke: white;
    stroke-width: 3.97;
    stroke-miterlimit: 22.9256
}

.str1 {
    stroke: #999999;
    stroke-width: 3.97;
    stroke-miterlimit: 22.9256
}

.fil1 {
    fill: none
}

.fil0 {
    fill: #333333
}

.sound {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.audiodb {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.levels {
    position: absolute;
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: 5%;
    top: 5%;
    height: 1px;
    left: 10%;
    background: silver;
    z-index: 300;
}

.level1 {
    top: 15%;
}

.level2 {
    top: 35%;
}

.level3 {
    top: 95%;
}

.audioBackground {
    width: 30%;
    height: 90%;
    left: 20%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5%;
    background: #ff0000;
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ff0000 0%, #ff0000 7%, #faff00 20%, #00ff2a 38%, #006d10 100%);
    /* FF3.6-15 */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #ff0000), color-stop(7%, #ff0000), color-stop(20%, #faff00), color-stop(38%, #00ff2a), color-stop(100%, #006d10));
    /* Chrome4-9,Safari4-5 */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ff0000 0%, #ff0000 7%, #faff00 20%, #00ff2a 38%, #006d10 100%);
    /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ff0000 0%, #ff0000 7%, #faff00 20%, #00ff2a 38%, #006d10 100%);
    /* Opera 11.10-11.50 */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ff0000 0%, #ff0000 7%, #faff00 20%, #00ff2a 38%, #006d10 100%);
    /* IE10 preview */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ff0000 0%, #ff0000 7%, #faff00 20%, #00ff2a 38%, #006d10 100%);
    /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ff0000', endColorstr='#006d10', GradientType=0);
}

.audioRight {
    left: 60%;
}

.audioCover {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30%;
    background: grey;
}

.audioNumbers {
    width: 10%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
}

.db {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    left: 15%;
}

.db p {
    margin-top: -5px;
}

.max {
    top: 5%;
}

.high {
    top: 15%;
}

.normal {
    top: 35%;
}

.low {
    top: 95%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/css-element-queries/0.4.0/ResizeSensor.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/css-element-queries/0.4.0/ElementQueries.min.js"></script>
<table class="channels ui-draggable ui-resizable" style="width: 476px; height: 266px; position: relative;" oncontextmenu="return false;"
    id="mainDiv">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="channelHeader ui-draggable-handle">
            <td colspan="5" class="channelName" id="channel1" audiopid="[0x33]" audiostream1="format:mp2,type:audio,pid:[0x33],width:0,height:0"
                interface="192.168.222.15" method="info" multicast="239.10.20.101" port="6000" protocol="udp" resolution="1920x1080"
                serviceid="1" servicename="undefined" serviceprovider="provider" videopid="[0x31]" videostream="format:h264,type:video,pid:[0x31],width:1920,height:1080">undefined</td>
            <td colspan="2" class="channelNumber">1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="audioVideo">
            <td colspan="5" class="vid"></td>
            <td colspan="2" class="sound">
                <div class="audiodb">
                    <div class="audioNumbers">
                        <span class="db max">
                            <p>0</p>
                        </span>
                        <span class="db high">
                            <p>6</p>
                        </span>
                        <span class="db normal">
                            <p>18</p>
                        </span>
                        <span class="db low">
                            <p>60</p>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="audioBackground audioLeft">
                        <div class="audioCover"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="audioBackground audioRight">
                        <div class="audioCover"></div>
                    </div>
                    <span class="levels level0"></span>
                    <span class="levels level1"></span>
                    <span class="levels level2"></span>
                    <span class="levels level3"></span>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="channelInfo">
            <td class="resolution">Resolution</td>
            <td class="aspect">Aspect</td>
            <td class="fps">FPS</td>
            <td class="vformat">V-Format</td>
            <td class="aformat">A-Format</td>
            <td>Left</td>
            <td>Right</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="channelInfoValues">
            <td class="resolValue">1920x1080</td>
            <td class="aspectValue">---</td>
            <td class="fpsValue">---</td>
            <td class="vformatValue">H-264</td>
            <td class="aformatValue">MP2</td>
            <td class="leftBarValue">---</td>
            <td class="rightBarValue">---</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Updated**

I have updated the code snippet to fit your needs as i misunderstood the question in the first place. The transform now happens on the tbody and the table acts like a container.

Comment: Now I understand what you mean. Sorry, I asked wrong question. I need user to be able to zoom to any part of the table. My actual table is much bigger than in the fiddle and user should be able to point with pointer what part he wants to zoom. I need to use transform origin for that purpose. My transform origin must be the pointer location on the table, which happens. But if the user moves mouse and zooms again, table jumps to the pointer and then gets zoomed, which is not what I want.

Comment: So the table should be fixed and only it`s content be zoomed in and out

Comment: Yes, like it happens on google maps. User must be able to zoom to any part of the table

Comment: Seems good. I'll try this out in my project as soon as i'll be able and accept if it works

Comment: It still jumps when I move the pointer to another point and scroll... Plus, user can't see full table after zoom.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use jquery panzoom. It can do what I think you look forward to achieve. It will also allow you to pan beside the zoom feature.